# How to align DropdownButton next to a TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to vertically align a `DropdownButton` right next to a `TextField`.

```
  Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      DropdownButton<String>(
        ...
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: TextField(
          ...
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

The current behavior is:

[image]

As you can see, the bottom lines aren't aligned. I guess that's happening due to a differences in height. What would be a good practice to fix that? (I'm guessing not using a fixed height)

---

My final goal is something like this:

[image]

Where both lines and the text of `DropdownButton` and `TextField` are vertically aligned.

Comment: How about some padding?

Comment: @10101010 I would have to set a fixed padding, and it would still be considered as a bad practice? (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I really don't know what is "good practice" here. That's what fixes it. I am not sure how it is gonna break anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up editing the padding of the `TextField`'s content, and used `CrossAxisAlignment.center` instead of `CrossAxisAlignment.start`:

```
  Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      DropdownButton<String>(
        ...
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Result:

[image]

(You see space between them due to a SizedBox added)

Answer (score 9):

Hope this helps but I got it working! Key prop that did it for me was setting `contentPadding` for widgets in row to `0.0`

```
Row(
   children: <Widget>[
       Flexible(
       flex: 2,
       child: TextFormField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
          WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
          ],
          decoration: InputDecoration(
             labelText: 'Width',
             contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          ),
          onChanged: (String newValue) {
             _stashItem.width = "$newValue $_widthUnit";
          },
          )),
          Flexible(
          flex: 1,
          child: DropdownButtonFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
             contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0)
          ),
          value: _widthUnit,
          items: ['cm', 'm', 'in', 'ft', 'yd']
              .map((String unit) =>
                 DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                   value: unit, child: Text(unit)))
                   .toList(),
          onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
              _widthUnit = value;
          })),
          )
          ],
       ),
```

Comment: this works well for me, using ```contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0)```

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but I had the same issue albeit with a slightly different layout:

1. I used `TextFormField` rather than `TextField`.
2. I used `DropdownButtonFormField` rather than `DropDownButton`.
3. Both fields were wrapped in `Flexible` widgets within the `Row`, with `mainAxisSize` set to `MainAxisSize.min`.
4. My text field was laid out to the left of the dropdown.

---

That being said, **setting `crossAxisAlignment` to `CrossAxisAlignment.end` worked** for me.

---

**Try this:**

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,  // see 3
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(  // see 3
      child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(  // see 2
        ...
      ),
    ),
    Flexible(
      child: TextFormField(  // see 1
        ...
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this solution helps you or not, but I think its better than using `row`.

```
 TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
       prefix: DropdownButton(underline: Container(), ...)
    ),
 )
```

Comment: That's causing a weird behavior: It's not exactly right next to each other, but the `DropdownButton`  is "inside" the `TextField`, causing a large gap between the text and the bottom line, also the `DropdownButton` is only visible when focusing the `InputDecoration`. Demo: https://i.imgur.com/qmCYSgK.png

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Row(
    Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        flex: 1
        child: ButtonTheme(
                   alignedDropdown: true,
                   child: DropdownButton<String>(
        ...
      ))),
       Expanded(
         flex: 6
         child: TextField(
          ...
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Comment: That's making the gap even larger. Demo: https://i.imgur.com/I1SDbKk.png

Comment: try it out with ButtonTheme(alignedDropdown: true

Comment: I tried it with `crossAxisAlignment` of `end/start/center`. With `end` it's the same behavior. With other values the gap changes. With `center` the text is aligned (which is great), but the border never aligns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
      //TODO: Customize the underline here
      bottom: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.white70,
        width: 0.5,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      DropdownButton<String>(
        onChanged: (c) {},
        underline: Container(),
        items: [
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text('Email'),
          )
        ],
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: It's great when the `TextField` is empty: https://i.imgur.com/Z7ykAxL.png But when there's some text in it, the border goes down a bit: https://i.imgur.com/snUfOff.png. Also the text of the `DropdownButton` and the `TextField` aren't aligned. My final goal is something like this: https://i.imgur.com/J9RENqB.png

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I needed a space between the two, and in your case there will be one line without a space. I ended up changing the content's padding. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can simply **decrease contentPadding** in `InputDecoration` of `DropdownButtonFormField`